# Custom scrollbar packages React

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar

Hi i was wondering if anyone knew of a good custom scrollbar package. I've tried to use react-custom-scrollbars, however it doesn't seem to work well with what i am trying to achieve. It seems as though with this package there are a few limitations that come with it. I have added an image of what i would like to create, it is a horizontal scrollbar. The thumb would be able to include an icon and should be draggable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### The bad news:

Implementing custom scrollbars is notoriously hard, and as a result there aren't really many packages to help you. If you go down the route of implementing one yourself, you'll need to consider (non-exhaustively):

- Mobile support. How is the design you've provided going to shrink to mobile displays?
- Accessibility. Are people using accessibility tools to control their browser still going to be able to use your custom scrollbar? Will they even know it's there (if they are using a screen reader?)
- Performance. You'll need to update the positioning of your content in CSS based on JS events, which may be laggy if you're not careful.
- Cross-browser and multi-OS support. Edge on Windows is one thing, Safari on macOS is another, Firefox on Linux is another still.

Generally (especially for accessibility reasons) it's best to just use the browser default scrollbars.

### The good news:

You should be able to get quite close to your design using CSS to style the browser-provided scrollbar implementation. Check out these resources:

- https://ishadeed.com/article/custom-scrollbars-css/
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-scrollbars
- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp